# grunt error TS2304 cannot find name

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, typescript, definitelytyped

I'm struggling with `error TS2304: Cannot find name 'ICookiesService'`. Despite I searched for solutions I don't seem to find one. I believe the reference is correct. I loaded the module ngCookies in app.ts and added the dependency.  What am I missing?

Many thanks for your help...

My controller looks like this:

```
/// <reference path='loginComponentScope.interface.ts' />
/// <reference path='xxx/angular-cookies.d.ts' />
/// <reference path='xxx/login.service.ts' />

'use strict';
   class LoginComponentController {

    public static $inject = [
      '$scope',
      '$cookies',
      'loginRestService'
    ];

    constructor( 
      private $scope: ILoginComponentScope,
              $cookies: ICookiesService,
              service: LoginService
    ) {
        ...     
        $cookies.put('securityToken', data);
        ...
```

angular-cookies.d.ts

```
 /// <reference path="angular.d.ts" />
    declare module "angular-cookies" {
        var _: string;
        export = _;
    }

    declare module angular.cookies {

        interface ICookiesService {
            [index: string]: any;
        }
    ...
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ICookiesService` is declared in the namespace `angular.cookies`. You need to reference it via that namespace (e.g. `angular.cookies.ICookiesService`), or use an `import` to create a shorter local name for it (e.g. `import ics = angular.cookies.ICookiesService`, then refer to it by `ics`)